# Trouble keeping buttons positioned at the bottom of the image - In responsive image gallery

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, image-gallery

I've made a image gallery and I'm stuck on this problem from from quite time now as I want to position next and previous button on the bottom of the image but how can I make the buttons relative to the image as images are different and changes. How to put controller button at the bottom of the image.

**What I'm trying to do:**

1. It has Full Screen background modal. (Done)
2. Upon that modal it shows images. (Done)
3. On image's bottom I want to keep a constant showing controller buttons which are next and previous button to change through images. (Stuck from two days)

**Tried Till Now:**

1. Tried to make buttons relative to div's class "modal-content and image" but according to width size my buttons moves.
2. Tried changing heights and widths of the divs and tried some other things too.
3. At the end when nothing worked. I tried to achieve layout in a improper way by positioning buttons all the way from 1900px to 400px by media queries. But it still doesn't look good and accurate. (Have to use media queries only.)
4. I know this is not a right way. What am I missing here? how to make elements responsive in this type of situations?

Please let me know by your expertise if I should try any different approach or If I do some mistakes with my CSS code.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.photos-thumbnail {
  width: 440px;
}

.photos-thumbnail img {
  margin: 10px 2px 0 0;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.view-all-photos:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.6%;
}

.pro-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.myslides img {
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
}

.controller {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #1A1A1A);
  text-align: center;
  height: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -110px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #02BFC1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 33px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 25pt;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.next {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.prev {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos-thumbnail">
  <img class="hover-shadow" onclick="openModal(); currentSlide(1)" src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/hitman_xbox_360_absolution_76000_1280x720.jpg">
  <img class="hover-shadow" onclick="openModal(); currentSlide(2)" src="https://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Hitman-Absolution-2-1280x720.jpg">
  <img class="hover-shadow" onclick="openModal(); currentSlide(3)" src="http://fextralife.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Far-Cry-4-Tiger.jpg">
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="pro-modal">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div onkeydown="ff(e)" class="mySlides">
      <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/hitman_xbox_360_absolution_76000_1280x720.jpg">
    </div>

    <div onkeydown="ff(e)" class="mySlides">
      <img src="https://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Hitman-Absolution-2-1280x720.jpg">
    </div>

    <div onkeydown="ff(e)" class="mySlides">
      <img src="http://fextralife.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Far-Cry-4-Tiger.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="controller">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="sep">|</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Output I want Even While Resizing

[image: Output I want Even While Resizing]

[image: This happens after Browser window Resize. Image will start to fit the window and shrink as I want but buttons will be statically at the bottom.]

This happens after Browser window Resize. Image will start to fit the window and shrink as I want but buttons will be statically at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the display of the slides to this:

```
slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline-grid";
```

and with a few additionally changes at the css it should work.

[image: green marks are my changes]
*The green marks are my changes*.

I inserted a smaller image so that you can see the result in the code below.
I hope it helps.

EDIT:

To make the images resizing just add to your css:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

And if you want the buttons staying in the middle during resizing, just put the `controller` div into the `mySlides` div -> see my code snippet

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline-grid";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.photos-thumbnail {
  width: 440px;
}

.photos-thumbnail img {
  margin: 10px 2px 0 0;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.view-all-photos:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.6%;
}

.pro-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.mySlides img {
  padding-left:75px;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  margin-right:75px;
  margin-top:25px;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
}

.controller {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #1A1A1A);
  
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.prev,
.next {
text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #02BFC1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 25pt;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.next {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.prev {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos-thumbnail">
  <img class="hover-shadow" onclick="openModal(); currentSlide(1)" src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/hitman_xbox_360_absolution_76000_1280x720.jpg">
  <img class="hover-shadow" onclick="openModal(); currentSlide(2)" src="https://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Hitman-Absolution-2-1280x720.jpg">
  <img class="hover-shadow" onclick="openModal(); currentSlide(3)" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="pro-modal">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div onkeydown="ff(e)" class="mySlides">
      <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/hitman_xbox_360_absolution_76000_1280x720.jpg">
          <div class="controller">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="sep">|</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div onkeydown="ff(e)" class="mySlides">
      <img src="https://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Hitman-Absolution-2-1280x720.jpg">
          <div class="controller">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="sep">|</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div onkeydown="ff(e)" class="mySlides">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
          <div class="controller">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="sep">|</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working well.. See when I resize the window my own code makes the image resize automatically due to "object-fit: contain". 

The images stays at middle of the page while resizing window. But problem I'm facing is with buttons which stays at the bottom but doesn't go up and coup with image auto resize while resizing browser. 

It stays statically at the bottom as I'm not able to relate these buttons with the image. It is still static with your code too.

Comment: Which browser do you use? In Chrome and Firefox for me the image isn't resizing at all, it just sticks at the left side. So you want that the image is resizing and the buttons are staying in the middle of the image?

Comment: I just updated my post with image example please check that too. I'm using Chrome with Brackets IDE Live View feature. And yes in my browser too image is being on the left and the button above it at the bottom.. But the problem now is that, image is not resizing with browser window resize. Image is not responsive. That's why object fit: contain, width: 100% and height: 90% was there in my CSS. And while image resize according to window size I want buttons at the bottom of the image.

Comment: See my edit, this should solve your problem, if I understood you right.

Comment: Ohooo! Feeling happy. You did it! Thank you..

But could we keep that image at the center automatically while resizing and while having button as same right now at bottom.. currently image is being at the top.

Comment: I changed a few styles to center the image (see the codesnippet). With the margin-top of .mySlides you can adjust the height of the images like you want.

Comment: Yes, but with your solution I came back to my very old problem due to little bit different images sizes controller was changing its position. Height: 90% and Object fit: contain was stabilizing image. If there was a small image then controller was going up (small image's bottom). So every time user would have to change mouse position to click next or previous. Couldn't achieve what I was having in mind. So, at the end I changed my controller design. Put the controllers to the very left (prev) and right (next) of image modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: flex`, `justify-content: (wherever in the image you want your buttons to be)`, and `text-align` to centre your buttons and their text.

Comment: No I'm not down voting. Thanks for the answer.. But, I can't use flex as I.E. below version 10 doesn't support it. Can we do something else?